# Are these functions equivalent?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, distribution

I am building a neural network that makes use of [T-distribution noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution). I am using functions defined in the numpy library `np.random.standard_t` and the one defined in tensorflow `tf.distributions.StudentT`. The link to the documentation of the first function is [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.standard_t.html) and that to the second function is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/probability/api_docs/python/tfp/distributions/StudentT). I am using the said functions like below:

```py
a = np.random.standard_t(df=3, size=10000)  # numpy's function

t_dist = tf.distributions.StudentT(df=3.0, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)
sess = tf.Session()
b = sess.run(t_dist.sample(10000))
```

In the documentation provided for the Tensorflow implementation, there's a parameter called `scale` whose description reads

> The scaling factor(s) for the distribution(s). Note that scale is not technically the standard deviation of this distribution but has semantics more similar to standard deviation than variance.

I have set `scale` to be `1.0` but I have no way of knowing for sure if these refer to the same distribution.

---

Can someone help me verify this? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say they are, as their sampling is defined in almost the exact same way in both cases. This is how the sampling of [`tf.distributions.StudentT`](https://github.com/tensorflow/probability/blob/v0.7/tensorflow_probability/python/distributions/student_t.py#L236-L253) is defined:

```
def _sample_n(self, n, seed=None):
  # The sampling method comes from the fact that if:
  #   X ~ Normal(0, 1)
  #   Z ~ Chi2(df)
  #   Y = X / sqrt(Z / df)
  # then:
  #   Y ~ StudentT(df).
  seed = seed_stream.SeedStream(seed, "student_t")
  shape = tf.concat([[n], self.batch_shape_tensor()], 0)
  normal_sample = tf.random.normal(shape, dtype=self.dtype, seed=seed())
  df = self.df * tf.ones(self.batch_shape_tensor(), dtype=self.dtype)
  gamma_sample = tf.random.gamma([n],
                                 0.5 * df,
                                 beta=0.5,
                                 dtype=self.dtype,
                                 seed=seed())
  samples = normal_sample * tf.math.rsqrt(gamma_sample / df)
  return samples * self.scale + self.loc  # Abs(scale) not wanted.
```

So it is a standard normal sample divided by the square root of a chi-square sample with parameter `df` divided by `df`. The chi-square sample is taken as a gamma sample with parameter `0.5 * df` and rate `0.5`, which is equivalent (chi-square is a special case of gamma). The `scale` value, like the `loc`, only comes into play in the last line, as a way to "relocate" the distribution sample at some point and scale. When `scale` is one and `loc` is zero, they do nothing.

Here is the implementation for [`np.random.standard_t`](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.4/numpy/random/src/legacy/legacy-distributions.c#L157-L163):

```c
double legacy_standard_t(aug_bitgen_t *aug_state, double df) {
  double num, denom;

  num = legacy_gauss(aug_state);
  denom = legacy_standard_gamma(aug_state, df / 2);
  return sqrt(df / 2) * num / sqrt(denom);
})
```

So essentially the same thing, slightly rephrased. Here we have also have a gamma with shape `df / 2` but it is standard (rate one). However, the missing `0.5` is now by the numerator as `/ 2` within the `sqrt`. So it's just moving the numbers around. Here there is no `scale` or `loc`, though.

In truth, the difference is that in the case of TensorFlow the distribution really is a [noncentral t-distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_t-distribution). A simple empirical proof that they are the same for `loc=0.0` and `scale=1.0` is to plot histograms for both distributions and see how close they look.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
np.random.seed(0)
t_np = np.random.standard_t(df=3, size=10000)
with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as sess:
    tf.random.set_random_seed(0)
    t_dist = tf.distributions.StudentT(df=3.0, loc=0.0, scale=1.0)
    t_tf = sess.run(t_dist.sample(10000))
plt.hist((t_np, t_tf), np.linspace(-10, 10, 20), label=['NumPy', 'TensorFlow'])
plt.legend()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: Distribution histograms]

That looks pretty close. Obviously, from the point of view of statistical samples, this is not any kind of proof. If you were not still convinced, there are some statistical tools for testing whether a sample comes from a certain distribution or two samples come from the same distribution.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. I was looking for an empirical proof, which you've addressed.